# Invalid mime type in spring rest template?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-rest, jackson2

I am just trying to make a simple REST request like below

```
String url = "some url";
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "some authorization");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
Body body = new Body();
body.setRemarks("test");
org.springframework.http.HttpEntity request = new org.springframework.http.HttpEntity(body, headers);
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, request, String.class);
    System.out.println("Status Response: "+ response.getStatusCode() +". Body: "+ response.getBody());
} catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Problem is every time I do this in Java the result is unpredictable I am usually getting this error consistently.

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "text/plain, application/json, application/json, application/*+json, application/*+json, */*; charset=UTF-8": Invalid token character ',' in token "plain, application/json, application/json, application/*+json, application/*+json, */*"
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:452)
at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getCharset(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
```

However when I try the same request through postman it works. I am missing something very simple and I do not know what.

I checked the response from Postman and the headers, and they seem to hold good like `Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8` and the response is also well formed.

I am also not able to make out which part whether the request or the response is on which Rest Template is having a problem.

Comment: Try to place jackson converter on first position `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());`. If it doesn't help then I suggest you to use debugger and descent deeply into RestTemplate.

Comment: give us a fulle restController code.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode I do not have the controller code, this is on the REST client API I am trying to hit, and build by their team. I am able to hit it with Postman successfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer in my case was add these extra headers while before making the request.

```
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Long answer: Thanks to [Nikolay Shevchenko's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224047/nikolay-shevchenko) suggestion to use debugger to dig out that when there was an error on the server `RestTemplate` tried to gather up all headers and body from the response to create sane exception message. While trying to create that message from response it got the mime type

```
text/plain, application/json, application/json, application/*+json, application/*+json, */*; charset=UTF-8
```

Yes that entire length of text instead of `application/json; charset=UTF-8` as shown for the same request by [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com). So in my case of an older spring rest template version when it tries to [parse over](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9801afb85d9cbbc76bd222e7e577460dd7806919/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java#L509) the above provided mime type, it fails, producing this message.

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "text/plain, application/json, application/json, application/*+json, application/*+json, */*; charset=UTF-8": Invalid token character ',' in token "plain, application/json, application/json, application/*+json, application/*+json, */*"
```

So instead of a getting a server error, a more fine grained mime type exception bubbles up from deeper stack, making no sense for what you are searching for.

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44766694) by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) `RestTemplate` was some how ending up using `StringHttpMessageConverter` although I have specified Jackson to Http Message converter as shown below.

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

As mentioned in aforementioned post having `StringHttpMessageConverter` causes `writeAcceptCharset` to be `true` which brings along the long format of mime type with almost every possible value. In the mentioned post the solutions were either to make `writeAcceptCharset` as `false` or not to write plain string but use object and then marshal it as a string.

For my use case I was expecting response type to be `application/json` with charset of `UTF-8` so setting up those accept headers in configuration sorted out my problem.