# Adding 'x-compound_text' charset into Java Spring application

Tags: java, spring, encoding, charset

We are deploying a Java Spring Web application to our Asian customer.

On Spring Web 5.3.3

On top of Tomcat 9

Using Java 11 on openjdk 11

On Linux RHEL 7.8 (Red hat Enterprise Linux)

Our Java Spring Web application is configured to use UTF-8 encoding.

#### In `setenv.sh`

```
...
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
...
```

#### In `server.xml`

```
 ...
   <Connector server="" port="7780" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               allowTrace="false"
               xpoweredBy="false"
               compression="on"
               compressionMinSize="2048"
               noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
               compressableMimeType="text/css,text/html,text/xml,application/javascript,application/json,application/x-javascript,text/plain,text/javascript"
                        />
  ...
```

#### Problem:

Our web service failing to consume chartset `x-compound_text`

Here are sections from the log:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: x-compound_text
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
....
Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: x-compound_text
        at java.base/java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:529)
        at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getAcceptCharset(HttpHeaders.java:694)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.getHttpHeader(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:817)
....
```

We understand we need to support charset `x-compound_text` in our application.

We understand JVM in lab and JVM in client site do not support charset `x-compound_text`.

The supported charsets are:

```
 Big5, Big5-HKSCS, CESU-8, EUC-JP, EUC-KR, GB18030, GB2312, GBK, IBM-Thai, IBM00858, IBM01140, IBM01141, IBM01142, IBM01143, IBM01144, IBM01145, IBM01146, IBM01147, IBM01148, IBM01149, IBM037, IBM1026, IBM1047, IBM273, IBM277, IBM278, IBM280, IBM284, IBM285, IBM290, IBM297, IBM420, IBM424, IBM437, IBM500, IBM775, IBM850, IBM852, IBM855, IBM857, IBM860, IBM861, IBM862, IBM863, IBM864, IBM865, IBM866, IBM868, IBM869, IBM870, IBM871, IBM918, ISO-2022-CN, ISO-2022-JP, ISO-2022-JP-2, ISO-2022-KR, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-13, ISO-8859-15, ISO-8859-16, ISO-8859-2, ISO-8859-3, ISO-8859-4, ISO-8859-5, ISO-8859-6, ISO-8859-7, ISO-8859-8, ISO-8859-9, JIS_X0201, JIS_X0212-1990, KOI8-R, KOI8-U, Shift_JIS, TIS-620, US-ASCII, UTF-16, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32, UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-Big5-HKSCS-2001, x-Big5-Solaris, x-euc-jp-linux, x-EUC-TW, x-eucJP-Open, x-IBM1006, x-IBM1025, x-IBM1046, x-IBM1097, x-IBM1098, x-IBM1112, x-IBM1122, x-IBM1123, x-IBM1124, x-IBM1129, x-IBM1166, x-IBM1364, x-IBM1381, x-IBM1383, x-IBM29626C, x-IBM300, x-IBM33722, x-IBM737, x-IBM833, x-IBM834, x-IBM856, x-IBM874, x-IBM875, x-IBM921, x-IBM922, x-IBM930, x-IBM933, x-IBM935, x-IBM937, x-IBM939, x-IBM942, x-IBM942C, x-IBM943, x-IBM943C, x-IBM948, x-IBM949, x-IBM949C, x-IBM950, x-IBM964, x-IBM970, x-ISCII91, x-ISO-2022-CN-CNS, x-ISO-2022-CN-GB, x-iso-8859-11, x-JIS0208, x-JISAutoDetect, x-Johab, x-MacArabic, x-MacCentralEurope, x-MacCroatian, x-MacCyrillic, x-MacDingbat, x-MacGreek, x-MacHebrew, x-MacIceland, x-MacRoman, x-MacRomania, x-MacSymbol, x-MacThai, x-MacTurkish, x-MacUkraine, x-MS932_0213, x-MS950-HKSCS, x-MS950-HKSCS-XP, x-mswin-936, x-PCK, x-SJIS_0213, x-UTF-16LE-BOM, X-UTF-32BE-BOM, X-UTF-32LE-BOM, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp
```

I am **able** to reproduce the problem in lab using debugger:

```
1. Start web application in Exclipse or remote debug.
2. Wait for application to complete loading.
3. Set breakpoint  in method java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup, a line before function returns
4. Load a page in application
5. When stopped in breakpoint change value to variable charsetName.
6. Set value to variable charsetName: x-compound_text
7. Continue running
8. Inspect log file
```

**I need advice, how to add support for charset `x-compound_text` into our Spring Web application.**

Comment: That looks like a defunct encoding to me. Not even a Wikipedia on it. What's wrong with Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to support x-compound_text?
Check this issue, it helped me a lot in the same case : [Java Spring RestTemplate sets unwanted headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762794/java-spring-resttemplate-sets-unwanted-headers)

Comment: thanks for suggesting. we eventually decided we officially do not support x-compound_text. Clients required to use official Java 11 charsets.

Comment: An answer should be self contained